# How can I retain the expanded/collapsed state of Angular material table rows after reloading the component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm following [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6jz81?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts) stackblitz link to make a collapsible/expandable material table, but every time I refresh the page, all of the rows collapse. How can I preserve each row in its expanded/collapsed state even after the component is reloaded? So far, I've tried and failed to accomplish this using localStorage. So any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you give a code or stackblitz link to understand correctly?

Comment: This is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6jz81?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html